# Acrobat Combo Box return the Item Selected not the export Value

Tags: javascript, adobe

Is there a better way to get the Select Text of a ComboBox  and not the export value?

Here's what i found so far.

```
//  combobox Return the export value 
var expValue = this.getField("Dropdown1").value;

//  combobox return the Selection by Indice
var i = this.getField("ItemType1").currentValueIndices;
console.println(this.getField("ItemType1").getItemAt(i,false));
```

Just try to find a simpler way of doing this.
This is not event triggered code so 'change' property, and 'changeEX' property will not Work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is how it's done. You could create a document-level function to make it a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply
I would've created a Doc Level Function for this, if I had to return the selection more then once. So here's how I believe it would be done.

```
function ReturnSelection(fieldName){
    // Check that Field is ComboBox or List Box
    var fldField = this.getField(fieldName);

    if(fldField != null && (fldField.type === "combobox" || fldField.type === "listbox")){
        //  combobox return the Selection by Indice
        var i = fldField.currentValueIndices;
        return fldField.getItemAt(i,false);

    }else{
        return "";
    }
 }
```

not tested.

and to return multi Selections

```
function ReturnSelection(fieldName){
    // Check that Field is ComboBox or List Box
    var fldField = this.getField(fieldName);
    if(fldField != null && (fldField.type === "combobox" || fldField.type === "listbox")){
        //  combobox return the Selection by Indice
        var i = fldField.currentValueIndices;
        if(typeof i == "number"){
            return fldField.getItemAt(i,false);
        }else{ // Deal With Multi Selections
            var arr = [];
            for(var a = 0; a < i.lenght){
                arr.push(fldField.getItemAt(i[a],false));
            }
            return arr;
        }   
    }else{ // Not a Combo or list box
        return "";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks good. I would suggest handling the case of the getField method returning null, which will happen if you specify a field that doesn't exist and in certain other circumstances.